# How to validate JWT token using identity server 4 in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt

I have an idenityserver4, a front-end angular app, and a Django rest framework resource API. The Angular app is unaccessible if not logged, and redirect to the identityserver4. The user has to log in there and is redirected to the front-end. So far so good, the provider gives the front-end a JWT access token.

Then the frontend application asks for resources to the DRF API providing the JWT. That's where I'm stuck, all the tutorials I find on google explain how to create your own provider. But I just want to get the token, check with the identity server 4 that it's valid, authenticate the user, provide the resources

Any code snippet or library will be highly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Using JWT, you need to first get the access token let's say /get-token/ which takes username and password as POST form data, the token is generated on the same if creds are valid, if the creds are valid the response will contain access and refresh tokens. You can now use the received access token in all of your subsequent API calls. Hope it answers your question

Comment: @danish_wani I already have access token generated by identity server. Angular application pass that access token in authorization header to call Django rest api. My requirement is to validate that token from external provider and then proceed the request in DRF

Comment: IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core 2 [source: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html]. I am not sure whether you can use django framework with IdentityServer4.

Comment: @danish_wani yes, Identityserver4 is built on top of .net core.
But here in Django rest framework, I need an interface that can validate either the provided token is valid or not by handshaking with the issuer, and the issuer in my case is identityserver4, I need such library

Comment: sorry, I can't help you with that. Wait for the right people to help you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I haven't fully solved, but maybe this can help you.

It is a permission class that only checks if a given jwt is properly encoded and signed using [authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/jose/index.html), from there you can access the token internal information to do further validation.

permissions.py:

```
from authlib.jose import jwt
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class TokenNotValid(APIException):
    status_code = 403
    default_detail = "Invalid or absent JWT token field."

class NoAuthHeader(APIException):
    status_code = 403
    default_detail = "Absent 'Authorization' header."


class ValidJWTPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for JWT token.
    """

    def _get_pubkey(self):
        # You will probably need to change this to get the
        # public key from your identity server and not from a file.
        with open("../public.pem", "rb") as key_file:
            pubk = key_file.read()
        return pubk

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        auth_header = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        # print("Received header:")
        # print(auth_header)
        if auth_header is None:
            raise NoAuthHeader

        try:
            token = auth_header.split()[1]
            # print("Encoded Token:")
            # print(token)
            dec_token = jwt.decode(token,self._get_pubkey())
        except Exception:
            # Probably should add proper exception handling.
            raise TokenNotValid

        # print("Decoded token:")
        # print(dec_token)

        return True
```

views.py:

```
from .permissions import ValidJWTPermission

class HelloView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [ValidJWTPermission]

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the gerenciador index.")
```